# MATLAB - Curves of Pursuit (Predator/Prey)

Tags: matlab, simulation, differential-equations

In my engineering class we are programming a "non-trivial" predator/prey pursuit problem.

Here's the gist of the situation:
There is a prey that is trying to escape a predator. Each can be modeled as a particle that can be animated in MATLAB (we have to use this coding language).

The prey:
can maneuver (turn) easier than the predator can
The predator:
can move faster than the prey

I have to create code for both the predator and the prey, which will be used in a class competition.

This is basically what the final product will look like:
http://www.brown.edu/Departments/Engineering/Courses/En4/Projects/pred_prey.gif

The goal is to catch the other team's prey in the shortest amount of time, and for my prey to become un-catchable for the other team's predator (or at least escape for a long period of time).

Here are the specific design constraints:
3. Design Constraints:
Predator and prey can only move in the x-y plane
Simulations will run for a time period of 250 seconds.
Both predator and prey will be subjected to three forces: (a) The propulsive force; (b) a viscous drag
force; and (c) a random time-varying force. (all equations given)
1. The propulsive forces will be determined by functions provided by the two competing groups
The predator is assumed to catch the prey if the distance between predator and prey drops below 1m.
You may not use the rand() function in computing your predator/prey forces – the only random forces
should be those generated by the script provided. (EOM with random forces are impossible for the
ODE solver to integrate, and it ends up in an infinite loop).
For the competition, we will provide the MATLAB code that will compute and animate the trajectories of
the competitors, and will determine the winner of each contest. The test code will be working in SI units.

I am looking for any resources that may be able to help me with some strategy. I have looked at basic pursuit curves, but I would love to look at some examples where the prey is not moving in a straight line. Any other coding advice or strategies would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea to start with the fundamentals in any field, and you can't go past the work of [Issacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rufus_Isaacs_%28game_theorist%29) ([Differential Games: A mathematical theory with applications to warfare and pursuit, control and optimization](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486406822)). This will almost certainly end up being a reference in any academic research project you may end up writing up.

Steven Lavalle's excellent book [Motion Planning](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/) has a number of aspects that may be of interest including a section on visibility based [pursuit evasion](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/ch12.pdf).

As for many mathematical topics, Wolfram Mathworld has some good diagrams and links that might get you thinking in the right direction (eg [Pursuit Curves](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PursuitCurve.html)).

If you want to have a look at a curious problem in the area that is well understood try the [Homicidal chauffeur problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homicidal_chauffeur_problem) - this will at least give you some grounds for comparing complexity / efficiency of different techniques. In particular, this is probably a good way to get a feel for level set methods (the paper [Homicidal Chaueur Game. Computation of Level Sets of the Value Function](http://www-m6.ma.tum.de/~turova/html/maas.pdf) by Patsko and Turova appears to have a number of images that might be helpful)